# Rails, construct url for arbitrary controller,action and zero or more params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

here is my current workflow:

```
c = get_some_controller # => "fruits" or nil
a = get_some_action # => "list"
p = get_some_params # => { :type => :orange, :price => 10 }

url = url_for(:controller => c, :action => a) # no option for params ??
```

So, here is my question, `url_for` seem does not have any option to pass params.

I guess this use case is pretty common, but rails for some reason not support it or i missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass params as additional keys:

`url_for(p.merge(:controller => c, :action => a))`

Or to perhaps be more clear, you could also have done:

`url_for(:controller => c, :action => a, :type => :orange, :price => 10)`